# How to print ASCII white space from file

Tags: python

I try to found on google but was useless... I use pycharm and I want to print file lines with ascii white space like "\n", "\t", "\r", etc. but all I get is just the normal string like I see it with any text editor but I want to see and that characters to to know how to reproduce that text file for some personal projects.
I do not what to make them by my self so I want to shoe them on console and to just copy-paste them.
Thanks in advance.

```py
# Local variable
fileName = r"C:\Users\...\textFile.txt"

# Create .mcmeta file
def mcmetaMaker(fileName=fileName):
    try:
        with open(file=fileName, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            line = f.readline()

            while line:
                print("\b{}".format(line))
                line = f.readline()
    finally:
        f.close()
```

Comment: How do you import your text? Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Local variable
fileName = r"C:\Users\...\textFile.txt"

# Create .mcmeta file
def mcmetaMaker(fileName):
    try:
        with open(fileName, mode='rb') as f:
            line = f.readline()

            while line:
                betterline = str(line)
                print(betterline[2:len(betterline)-1])
                line = f.readline()
    finally:
        f.close()
```

This worked for me. The `'b'` in `'rb'` stands for binary mode, which doesn't change the original bytes of the string. 
`print(line)` produces `b'asdf\r\n'` so I converted it to string and sliced it. Hope it doesn't run too slow this way.

Comment: Will this catch spaces and tabs, say in `b'\tas df\r\n'`

Comment: Was not so usefull because for me was not show and the the horizontals space (\t), but that "rb" was opening my eyes and I fix it manually (down is my final solved problem) =]] thank's.

Oh in fact was work and your solution. the problem was on my text file. In fact I had not horizontal space, just two spaces. Thank's again.